# Deleting a large number of rows by copying rows to keep into temporary table, dropping original table, and copying rows back

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in an SQL Server 2012 database that has over 30 million rows, most of which I need to delete.  However, deleting those rows takes far too long (we're talking multiple days).

The most likely solution I've found online is one where I use a SELECT INTO query to grab all the rows I want to keep and put them in a temporary table, the DROP the original table before using another SELECT INTO statement to repopulate the original table from the temporary table.

However, I've run into the problem where I can't drop the original table because it is referenced by foreign key constraints.  I've used the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[foreign_keys] WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('OriginalTable')
```

To get the foreign key constraints, but when I try ALTER TABLE OriginalTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraint name], I get a message saying that the constraint does not belong to the table.

My goal is to remove these 30 million rows without altering the state of my database, so I want to keep any foreign keys intact.  Am I going about this the right way?  If so, how can I drop the original table?

Comment: what is the percentage of rows that you want to keep in this table ? You have FK to this table, meaning you would also required to delete from other tables first.

Comment: The percentage of rows that I want to keep is roughly 0.5%

Comment: how about 1. Drop the FK. 2. rename table(s) 3. recreate table(s) 4. insert from renamed to original table(s)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what "you have FK to this table, meaning you would also required to delete from other tables first" means.  I'm a complete SQL neophyte, really.  I'll probably need more specific explanations, sorry.

Comment: if that query from `sys.foreign_keys` produces result, you have fk to this table. So you can't just delete the rows from `OriginalTable`. add this to the query `object_name(parent_object_id)`  it will show what are the tables that references this `OriginalTable`

Comment: First the foreign key constraint exists on another table which references the table you are trying to delete from. So your alter table statement needs to alter the 'other' table. Secondly NOCHECK only affects future inserts updates - you'll need to drop the constraint to drop the table. Thirdly as @Squirrel says you need to handle the fact that your 'other' tables have a reference to this table which will be broken by the delete.

Comment: Okay, I was able to drop the constraints on the other tables, and then drop the table itself.  But it sounds like it isn't as simple as just copying the rows I want to keep into a new table with the same name?  I'm also not sure how to recreate the foreign key constraints, or even if I need to (I don't actually know what these do).  (I'm working with a backup of my database, so it doesn't matter if I completely ruin it, I can always restore.)

Comment: I think its fair to say you will want to recreate the foreign key constraints - once you decide what to do with all the hanging links. Just script the foreign keys as drop and create, and then save the scripts for later use.

Comment: I'm not sure what the hanging links are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with what appears to be a working solution:

**Step 1:** I use a SELECT INTO statement to back up the desired rows into a temporary table.

**Step 2:** I use SQL Server Management Studio's "Script Key As" functions to make DROP and CREATE sql scripts for the foreign key constraints.

**Step 3:** I drop the foreign key constraints using the created scripts.

**Step 4:** I TRUNCATE the original table.

**Step 5:** I use an INSERT INTO statement to copy all rows from my temporary table back into the truncated original table.

**Step 6:** I recreate the foreign key constraints using the created scripts.

**Step 7:** I drop the temporary table.

I believe this effectively deletes the rows I don't want, and leaves the database in the same state it was in at the start of the process (minus the rows I don't want, of course).

Comment: If you're dropping the constraints, why not just STEP 4 drop the original table. STEP 5 rename the temp table to same as original. STEP 7 no longer required

Comment: I don't know much about databases or SQL, and I was worried that dropping the original table and renaming the temporary one might break some links or something like that.

Comment: There would possibly be additional things like triggers and indexes to create - take a look by doing SCRIPT TABLE AS on your original table..

Comment: Thanks,  I used the SCRIPT TABLE and was able to compare the scripts for the original table versus the tables as it was after completing my process, and both scripts were identical.

Comment: Er.. yes,, your process does nothing with the original table, so you'd expect a SCRIPT TABLE to return the same thing no matter how many times it's run. The idea behind doing a SCRIPT TABLE is to check what triggers, foreign keys, contraints etc that your existing table has that a new table created by SELECT INTO wouldn't. My suggestion of dropping the original table and reinstating the pared down version in its place would possibly need additional things (indexes, triggers, constraints, relationships) doing (and the SCRIPT TABLE would tell you what) to restore normal operation

Comment: Ah.  Well, I used the script table function just to check that I hadn't broken anything.  Step 7 takes a couple of seconds, so it's no great gain to cut it out an risk breaking the triggers, constraints and relationships.